# Самопроизвольно выключается клавиша NumLock на Lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура, lubuntu

Самопроизвольно выключается клавиша <kbd>NumLock</kbd> на ОС Lubuntu при перезагрузке компьютера. Как устранить данную проблему?

Comment: 1. в какой именно момент выключается? («перезагрузка» — это очень сложный комплекс действий) 2. к какому именно моменту упомянутого комплекса действий вам нужен включенный numlock?

Comment: При каждом включении компьютера нужен, а он каждый раз выключен оказывается.

Comment: «при включении» — т.е., сразу после подачи питания? увы, это невозможно. первый из процессов, который может управлять состоянием клавиатуры, является bios/uefi. смотрите в его настройки (либо обратитесь к продавцу или производителю материнской платы или всего компьютера).

Comment: Дело не в плате. Numlock выключает система при или после загрузки, короче, когда уже ос загружена numlock выключен оказывается

Answer (score 0):

Это, правда, очень старый рецепт, но попробуйте так:

*/etc/rc.local:*

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Numlock enable
[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] && numlockx on

exit 0
```

Comment: нет такого файла в системе

Comment: мало того, что старый, так ещё и абсолютно неправильный. сразу на трёх уровнях: 1. программа numlockx — это x-клиент, а x-серврер мало того, что ещё не будет запущен к моменту выполнения скрипта, так если бы и был запущен, то связаться с ним программа не сможет. 2. программа numlockx сейчас по умолчанию в популярных дистрибутивах не установлена. 3. выполнение `/etc/rc.local` нынче по умолчанию отключено.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin - Ну так я же говорил - старый! :-) А по поводу пункта 3 - позвольте не согласиться! Именно в */etc/rc.local* у меня стоит монтирование USB диска. Вполне себе - монтируется!